# Is it possible to determine if a merge conflict occured given a commits parents?

Tags: git

I wanted to that, if given a commit A, and parents B and C, is it possible to know whether or not the attempted merge resulted in a merge-conflict for the end user which the user was required to manually resolve?

(edit: I am looking for a programmatic solution that doesn't rely upon the git toolchain. For example, is there a particular algorithm that I can run on the file contents of commits B and C?)

Comment: You can create a branch on `B`, check it out then merge `C` into it. If no conflict occurs you'll get a commit that has the same content as `A`; otherwise you won't get a commit but a list of conflicting changes :-)

Comment: @axiac That looks like a perfectly good answer to me. Would you post it as such?

Comment: I guess there is that way :) . I should have specified that I was looking for a programmatic solution. In other words, I have the raw commit object of commit A, B, and C. Is there any particular algorithm that I could use to check this or is there any metadata stored in A regaurding this?

Comment: @ZacRomero Eh? axiac's approach is easy to automate, it doesn't need to be done manually.

Comment: @hvd Definitely. I neglected to mention the use case. The github.com/src-d/go-git library seems to have trouble selecting the commits of the history of a particular file. See: https://github.com/src-d/go-git/blob/master/references.go#L103  My initial hunch was that it is impossible becuase the user could have used a varying number of merging strategies which some could have caused conflicts and others not. I'm not that knowledgable on this subject though so I'm not sure.

Comment: Suppose you have two branches `foo` and `bar`, you can try `git merge-tree $(git merge-base foo bar) foo bar` to test/dry-run what would happen if you merge `bar` to `foo`. `foo` and `bar` can be 2 specific commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question, no, Git does not store metadata on whether a merge commit had a manually resolved conflict. You cannot recover that information after the fact except by re-trying the merge. And you're right that whether you'll get a conflict depends on the exact options you pass to `git merge`, so you'd need to prompt the user for those options.

---

> I neglected to mention the use case. The github.com/src-d/go-git library seems to have trouble selecting the commits of the history of a particular file.

For that use case, detecting merge conflicts is insufficient.

Suppose you have a file

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

On branch 1, you change `B` to `b`.

On branch 2, you change `E` to `e`.

When you merge the two branches, you won't get a merge conflict, but you will get a version of the file that hadn't existed previously.

I think you should instead declare that a merge commit is relevant for the history of a file if and only if there is no parent commit in which that file has the same contents.

Comment: *I think you should instead declare that a merge commit is relevant for the history of a file if and only if there is no parent commit in which that file has the same contents.* This, not entirely incidentally, is also a rule Git uses in history simplification in `git log`: "If the commit was a merge, and it was TREESAME to one parent, follow only that parent."